# Having trouble changing color by pressing left or right button

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

I'm having trouble changing change the color when you from left to right button. Holding down the left mouse button and moving it inside the canvas should draw a trajectory of the mouse in motion of red dots and blue dots for when you hold down the right mouse button.

Problem is: once you drawn with the left button and go the right button it changes the color drawn by left button, and vise versa.

Need help or hints on how to fix this. Thank you.

javascript:

```
// Vertex shader program
var VSHADER_SOURCE =
    'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
    'void main() {\n' +
    '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
    '  gl_PointSize = 10.0;\n' +
    '}\n';

// Fragment shader program
var FSHADER_SOURCE =
    'precision mediump float;\n' +
    'uniform vec4 u_FragColor;\n' + 
    'void main() {\n' +
    '  gl_FragColor = u_FragColor;\n' +
    '}\n';

 var mousePressed = false;      // Holds boolean if mouse is pressed down
 var leftClick = false;         // Holds boolean if left click is pressed down
 var rightClick = false;        // Holds boolean if right click is pressed down

 function main() 
 {
    // Retrieve <canvas> element
    var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');

    // Get the rendering context for WebGL
    var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
    if (!gl) 
    {
        console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');

        return;
    }

    // Initialize shaders
    if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) 
    {
        console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
        return;
    }

    // Get the storage location of a_Position
    var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
    if (a_Position < 0) 
    {
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
        return;
    }

    // Get the storage location of u_FragColor
    var u_FragColor = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_FragColor');
    if (!u_FragColor) 
    {
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of u_FragColor');
        return;
    }

    // Register function (event handler) to be called on a mouse mousePressed
    canvas.onmousedown = function(ev)
    { 
    console.log('f1 called');
        // Identify which click is being press down
        switch (ev.which)
        {
            case 1:         // leftClick click
            leftClick = true;
            break;
            case 3:         // rightClick click
            rightClick = true;
            break;
        }

        // Mouse click is being pressed down
        mousePressed = true;

        // call function
        //console.log('calling f1');
        //drawDots(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position, u_FragColor, false); 
        //drawDots(ev, gl, a_Position, u_FragColor, false); 
    };

    canvas.onmousemove = function(ev)
    {
        console.log('f2 called');
        if (mousePressed)
        {
            console.log('calling drawDots');
            drawDots(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position, u_FragColor, true); 
        }
            //drawDots(ev, gl, a_Position, u_FragColor, true);
    };

    canvas.onmouseup = function(ev)
    {
        console.log('f3 called');
        mousePressed = false;
        leftClick = false;
        rightClick = false;
    };

    // Specify the color for clearing <canvas>
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    console.log('clearColor call');

    // Clear <canvas>
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    console.log('clear call');
}

var g_points = []; // The array for the position of a mouse mousePressed

function drawDots(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position, u_FragColor, down) 
//function drawDots(ev, gl, a_Position, u_FragColor, down)
{
    console.log('drawDots called');
    var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect() ;

    var x = ev.clientX; // x coordinate of a mouse pointer
    var y = ev.clientY; // y coordinate of a mouse pointer

    x = ((x - rect.left) - canvas.width/2)/(canvas.width/2);
    y = (canvas.height/2 - (y - rect.top))/(canvas.height/2);

    // For left click
    if (down == true && leftClick == true)
    {
        console.log('called left');
        // Store the coordinates to g_points array
        g_points.push(x); g_points.push(y);

        // Clear <canvas>
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        var len = g_points.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < len; i += 2) 
        {
            // Pass the position of a point to a_Position variable
            gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            gl.vertexAttrib3f(a_Position, g_points[i], g_points[i+1], 0.0);


            // Draw
            gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
        }
    }
    // Right click
    else if (down == true && rightClick == true)
    {
        console.log('called right');
        // Store the coordinates to g_points array
        g_points.push(x); g_points.push(y);

        // Clear <canvas>
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        var len = g_points.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i += 2) 
        {
            // Pass the position of a point to a_Position variable
            gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            gl.vertexAttrib3f(a_Position, g_points[i], g_points[i+1], 0.0);


            // Draw
            gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you don't store each point's color, no wonder why they are all the same color. drawDots can only draw in one single color right now. You should clarify a bit your code first (factorize), it will be easier to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each point you add to `g_points` you need to remember what color the point was created as. So you can create another array to keep track of the point colors.

```
var g_points = []; // The array for the position of a mouse mousePressed
var g_colors = [];
```

And add the color to the array every time you add a point.

```
// Store the coordinates to g_points array
g_points.push(x); g_points.push(y);

// Store the color
g_colors.push([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]);
```

Then update your for loop to use the given color for each point.

```
for(var i = 0; i < len; i += 2) 
{
    // Pass the position of a point to a_Position variable
    gl.uniform4fv(u_FragColor, g_colors[i/2]);
    gl.vertexAttrib3f(a_Position, g_points[i], g_points[i+1], 0.0);


    // Draw
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
}
```

Remember to update both the left click code and the right click code to store and use the color.

Here is your full code with the fix:

```js
// Vertex shader program
var VSHADER_SOURCE =
    'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
    'void main() {\n' +
    '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +
    '  gl_PointSize = 10.0;\n' +
    '}\n';

// Fragment shader program
var FSHADER_SOURCE =
    'precision mediump float;\n' +
    'uniform vec4 u_FragColor;\n' + 
    'void main() {\n' +
    '  gl_FragColor = u_FragColor;\n' +
    '}\n';

 var mousePressed = false;      // Holds boolean if mouse is pressed down
 var leftClick = false;         // Holds boolean if left click is pressed down
 var rightClick = false;        // Holds boolean if right click is pressed down

 function main() 
 {
    // Retrieve <canvas> element
    var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
    canvas.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    // Get the rendering context for WebGL
    //var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
    var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
    if (!gl) 
    {
        console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');

        return;
    }

    // Initialize shaders
    if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) 
    {
        console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
        return;
    }

    // Get the storage location of a_Position
    var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
    if (a_Position < 0) 
    {
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
        return;
    }

    // Get the storage location of u_FragColor
    var u_FragColor = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_FragColor');
    if (!u_FragColor) 
    {
        console.log('Failed to get the storage location of u_FragColor');
        return;
    }

    // Register function (event handler) to be called on a mouse mousePressed
    canvas.onmousedown = function(ev)
    { 
    console.log('f1 called');
        // Identify which click is being press down
        switch (ev.which)
        {
            case 1:         // leftClick click
            leftClick = true;
            break;
            case 3:         // rightClick click
            rightClick = true;
            break;
        }

        // Mouse click is being pressed down
        mousePressed = true;

        // call function
        //console.log('calling f1');
        //drawDots(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position, u_FragColor, false); 
        //drawDots(ev, gl, a_Position, u_FragColor, false); 
    };

    canvas.onmousemove = function(ev)
    {
        console.log('f2 called');
        if (mousePressed)
        {
            console.log('calling drawDots');
            drawDots(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position, u_FragColor, true); 
        }
            //drawDots(ev, gl, a_Position, u_FragColor, true);
    };

    canvas.onmouseup = function(ev)
    {
        console.log('f3 called');
        mousePressed = false;
        leftClick = false;
        rightClick = false;
    };

    // Specify the color for clearing <canvas>
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    console.log('clearColor call');

    // Clear <canvas>
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    console.log('clear call');
}

var g_points = []; // The array for the position of a mouse mousePressed
var g_colors = []; 

function drawDots(ev, gl, canvas, a_Position, u_FragColor, down) 
//function drawDots(ev, gl, a_Position, u_FragColor, down)
{
    console.log('drawDots called');
    var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect() ;

    var x = ev.clientX; // x coordinate of a mouse pointer
    var y = ev.clientY; // y coordinate of a mouse pointer

    x = ((x - rect.left) - canvas.width/2)/(canvas.width/2);
    y = (canvas.height/2 - (y - rect.top))/(canvas.height/2);

    // For left click
    if (down == true && leftClick == true)
    {
        console.log('called left');
        // Store the coordinates to g_points array
        g_points.push(x); g_points.push(y);

        // Store the color
        g_colors.push([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]);

        // Clear <canvas>
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        var len = g_points.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < len; i += 2) 
        {
            // Pass the position of a point to a_Position variable
            gl.uniform4fv(u_FragColor, g_colors[i/2]);
            gl.vertexAttrib3f(a_Position, g_points[i], g_points[i+1], 0.0);


            // Draw
            gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
        }
    }
    // Right click
    else if (down == true && rightClick == true)
    {
        console.log('called right');
        // Store the coordinates to g_points array
        g_points.push(x); g_points.push(y);

        // Store the color
        g_colors.push([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]);

        // Clear <canvas>
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        var len = g_points.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i += 2) 
        {
            // Pass the position of a point to a_Position variable
            gl.uniform4fv(u_FragColor, g_colors[i/2]);
            gl.vertexAttrib3f(a_Position, g_points[i], g_points[i+1], 0.0);


            // Draw
            gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initShaders(gl, vertexStr, fragmentStr) {
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, fragmentStr, true);
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, vertexStr, false);

    gl.program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(gl.program, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(gl.program, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(gl.program);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(gl.program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    }

    gl.useProgram(gl.program);

    return true;
}

function getShader(gl, str, isFrag) {
    var shader;
    if (isFrag) {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}
</script>
<body onload="main();">
    <canvas id="webgl" style="border: none;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```