# HTML/JavaScript not running on a blank chrome page?

Tags: javascript, html

Ok I am a beginner into html. I was working on a project and stacksoverflow have the codes of both JavaScript and html. here is the link : [Having trouble changing color by pressing left or right button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689194/having-trouble-changing-color-by-pressing-left-or-right-button)

I have to make this in notepad ++ . so I made an HTML file and js file in notepad ++ copied and pasted the corrected codes. but I can't open it on the browser. I am using chrome and other HTML projects are running except this. browser is blank like something is wrong with code. but the graphics are running on the "run code snippet" it is also working when I put HTML and js in one file. but I have to have it in 2 separate file in one folder. I am a beginner please help!

this is my html and js. file now

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sfmoix7c1llz4j6/AADu4XZP_pHgynCarGUbTwdEa?dl=0

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: You didn't just copy and paste the code in the link, right? Because the one in the link only shows the JavaScript and not the HTML.

Comment: By "2 separate files" I assume you mean 1 html and 1 js file. How are you linking to the js file from the html file?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably doing it wrong. If you have a separate file for html and javascript, this is an example of how you would use it.

**This assumes that your html file is 'theHtml.html' and your JavaScript file is 'theJS.js' ** FILE EXTENSIONS DO MATTER!!!!

**theHtml.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE Html />
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="theJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**theJS.js**

```
alert("Hello, World");
```

Also, make sure that both files exist within the same directory (for example, a folder called 'my web site' on your desktop)

Comment: hmm still not running. i put a link to my dropbox for the html file and js file. i am doing anything wrong

Comment: First of all, you made a modification to `theHtml.html`. You added in a line of code that is not valid which breaks everything. Remove line 1 (<!jay chacko, Jose Paul dot line project html>) and try again. I also noticed that your `theJS.js` has much more code than the example I provided. I'm not going to sort through all of your code to figure out the issue, so please revert to the 1 line of code I provided in the example. Once that is working, you should get the basic concept of a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Share your HTML and JS with us so we can see the problem more clearly.

In the HTML file, have you included a  tag pointing to your JS file?
It would be structured something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="thepathtomyjsfile.js"></script>
        //Some html stuff...
    </head>
</html>
```

Also make sure that there is some function or event listener to call your first function.

Comment: so my html name is dot line.html and js name is dot line.js                                                                                                             <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dot line.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: put your script tag in the <head>, not the <body>

Comment: . i put a link to my dropbox for the html file and js file. i am doing anything wrong??

Comment: Yeah, you're not calling any functions. You've only defined them. At the bottom of your JS file, after everything is defined you probably want to run main()